# Creating Total Row in SQL database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a query that will add an additional ROW in the database that is the total.

Below is what I'm starting with:

```
PerfAttribAlphaID  ProductID   AsOfDate    AlphaSourceDesc   PerfAttribValue
1                 1        2014-06-30   Currency        0.00000000
2                 1        2014-06-30   Macro           50.00000000
3                 1        2014-06-30   Quantitative    10.00000000
4                 1        2014-06-30   Credit          90.00000000
```

Below is what I'm trying to end with:

```
PerfAttribAlphaID  ProductID   AsOfDate    AlphaSourceDesc   PerfAttribValue
1                 1        2014-06-30   Currency        0.00000000
2                 1        2014-06-30   Macro           50.00000000
3                 1        2014-06-30   Quantitative    10.00000000
4                 1        2014-06-30   Credit          90.00000000
```

Where PerfAttribAlphaID is a primary key (bigint) and increments by one for each row in the table, ProductID and AsOfDate are input parameters, AlphaSourceDesc is Total and PerfAttribValue is the sum of all previous rows in the table.

Comment: Your Before and After appear to be identical.

Comment: PerfAttribAlphaID ProductID  AsOfDate     AlphaSourceDesc  PerfAttribValue    150.000000
5                     1      2014-06-30          Total
See the text for above for the inputs.

Comment: I can't think of any practical situation where this would be a good idea.   It's best to calculate your totals at query time rather than to try to keep them in the database.  Otherwise you will need to update the totals row every time you insert, update or delete a row.

Comment: how can I write it in the stored procedure to create a total row?

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing your query so I'm just guessing here, but basic idea is to use `union select`:

before:

```
select PerfAttribAlphaID, ProductID, AsOfDate, AlphaSourceDesc, PerfAttribValue
from T
```

after:

```
select PerfAttribAlphaID, ProductID, AsOfDate, AlphaSourceDesc, PerfAttribValue
from T
union 
select null, null, null,    'Total',   sum(PerfAttribValue)
from T
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **GROUPING SETS** to generate the total row:

```
select PerfAttribAlphaID, 
ProductID, 
AsOfDate, 
case when grouping(PerfAttribValue) = 1 then 'Total' else AlphaSourceDesc end AlphaSourceDesc,  
SUM(PerfAttribValue) PerfAttribValue
from MyTable
group by grouping sets((PerfAttribAlphaID, ProductID, AsOfDate, AlphaSourceDesc, PerfAttribValue), ())
```

This query could be modified if you have multiple ProductIds and want to get a subtotal for each one.  [This SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/281c3/1/0) demonstrates that.